# Why Rubocop do not allow html_safe or raw() Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

here is my code who do not pass Rubocop because :

> Rails/OutputSafety: Tagging a string as html safe may be a security risk.

```
def number_with_html_delimiter(num)
   number_with_delimiter(num)
      .gsub!(' ', content_tag(:span, "", class: "numbers-delimiter")).html_safe
end
```

I need to put a custom span with some css to put the spaces in HTML and when I remove html_safe it does not work.

Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest using `number_with_delimiter(num, delimiter: tag.span(class: 'numbers-delimiter')).html_safe` if you don't mind using a `<span>` delimiter for all locales, you currently only insert it if the locale uses a space limiter. Even if this is not the case, you don't want to be chaning `html_safe` to [`gsub!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub-21), since `gsub!` returns `nil` if no substitutions are made.

Comment: Thanks ! I used  number_with_delimiter(num, delimiter: tag.span(class: 'numbers-delimiter')) and it works !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`html_safe` and `raw()` are not safe for security purpose. You can disable `rubocop` for `html_safe`(or `raw`) by using `# rubocop:disable Rails/OutputSafety` and `# rubocop:enable Rails/OutputSafety` before and after code where you have used `html_safe`(or `raw`) method.

```
# rubocop:disable Rails/OutputSafety
def number_with_html_delimiter(num)
   number_with_delimiter(num)
      .gsub!(' ', content_tag(:span, "", class: "numbers-delimiter")).html_safe
end
#rubocop:enable Rails/OutputSafety
```

Comment: Disabling a rubocop rule doesn't solve the problem though.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use `sanitize` for common tags and attributes by [Rails docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-html_safe).

In your helper:

```rb
# Use `!` to indicate that `sanitize` should be used
def number_with_html_delimiter!(num)
   number_with_delimiter(num)
      .gsub(' ', content_tag(:span, "", class: "numbers-delimiter")).html_safe
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= sanitize number_with_html_delimiter!(1000) %>
```