# Rails: html_safe not safe?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I have this working piece of code:

```
content_tag('p', params[:text]&.html_safe, class: 'nice-class')
```

And I'm using RuboCop, which is telling me that "tagging a string as html safe may be a security risk". (Also using `raw()`)

As I understood in [Why Rubocop do not allow html_safe or raw() Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60213803/why-rubocop-do-not-allow-html-safe-or-raw-rails), there shouldn't be problems using `&` as it ignores the `html_safe` if the string is empty, but doesn't seem so.

Is there any other way to solve this or may I just ignore RuboCop.

Comment: The problem is not the `&`, but `html_safe`. Rendering unescaped user input is asking to get all kinds of security problems. Rubocop is correct in flagging this line.

Comment: You always need to validate and sanitize user input, not just the HTML itself.

Comment: https://makandracards.com/makandra/2579-how-to-use-html_safe-correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rubocop is flagging `params[:text]&.html_safe` as bad practice because this can expose your code to Cross site scripting attacks.

Even brakeman raises issue for such cases. [Check link](https://brakemanpro.com/2017/09/08/cross-site-scripting-in-rails#:%7E:text=In%20Rails%203%2C%20templates%20escaped%20output%20by%20default.%20Hooray!)

> In Rails 3, templates escaped output by default. Hooray!
> Sadly, Rails 3 also introduced the unfortunately named html_safe method to bypass this escaping. Quite a few people have been confused into thinking html_safe makes strings safe. What it really does is mark the string as “safe” so that it will not be escaped. (The raw method does the same thing.)

`html_safe` [api doc](https://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe) suggests to use `sanitize` instead

---

The code after using `sanitize` method will look like -

```rb
content_tag('p', sanitize params[:text], class: 'nice-class')
```